# Форматирование кода после получения

Tags: javascript

Ситуация такая:

Прилетает код:

```
function($k){$d = $t->d('c', $k); $d .= $t->f($d); return $d;}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он от форматировался сам сразу и стал таким:

```
function($k){
    $d = $t->d('c', $k); 
    $d .= $t->f($d); 
    return $d;
}
```

Может быть и такой код:

```
function($k, int $t= 0) {$f = c::f($k);if (0 < $t) {if ((time() - $t) > filemtime($f)) {return unlink($f);}}return is_file($f);}
```

Что должно получиться:

```
function($k, int $t= 0) {
    $f = c::f($k);
    if (0 < $t) {
        if ((time() - $t) > filemtime($f)) {
            return unlink($f);
        }
    }
    return is_file($f);
}
```

Как это делают многие другие сервисы (когда вставляем код, нажимаем кнопку и воаля - готово), как такой код написать, чтобы он сам автоматом форматирование проводил, когда запускается функция?

Я даже не могу врубиться, что для этого нужно и как это отследить.
Вариант с:

```
func.replace(/{/g, "\{\n  ").replace(/; /g, ";\n  ").replace(/;}/g, ";\n}");
```

Работает только если будет 1 тело функции, потом он просто сливается построчно без нужных табуляций.

По хорошему бы, одной регуляркой решить вопрос, было-бы замечательно.

Comment: можно регуляркой заменить символы `{` и `;` на `\{\n\r    ` и `;\n\r    ` соответственно

Comment: @slippyk, Не совсем то, я так пробовал делать,работает только на одном теле функции только `{}`, а если будут другие блоки `if{...}` они уже будут без табуляций внутри и все сливается построчно. Нужно, чтобы все отделялось, как работает это например [тут](https://beautifier.io/) любое количество блоков вложенности может быть, вот в чем проблема, не могу понять, как написать регулярку, которая это отследить, желательно 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто.
Берем [это](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.11.0/beautify.min.js) и радуемся:

```js
console.log(js_beautify('function($k, int $t= 0) {$f = c::f($k);if (0 < $t) {if ((time() - $t) > filemtime($f)) {return unlink($f);}}return is_file($f);}'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.11.0/beautify.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Да у меня тоже только что-то в таком духе приходит. 
А для чего это нужно?

```js
let myFunction = "function($k){$d = $t->d('c', $k); $d .= $t->f($d); return $d;}";
const neuFunction = myFunction.replace(/{/g, "\{\n  ").replace(/; /g, ";\n  ").replace(/;}/g, ";\n}");
console.log(neuFunction)
```

Comment: Не совсем то, я так пробовал делать,работает только на одном теле функции только `{}`, а если будут другие блоки `if{...}` они уже будут без табуляций внутри и все сливается построчно. Нужно, чтобы все отделалось, как работает это например [тут](https://beautifier.io/) любое количество блоков вложенности может быть, вот в чем проблема, не могу понять, как написать регулярку, которая это отследить, желательно 1.